# How to tell if Linearly Independent

Tags: linear-algebra

just a quick question. Do 2 vectors in R3 mean it is linearly independent?
The question " is [1 2 3], [0 2 3] linearly independent?" 
I solved it by saying there is no scalar multiple thus linearly independent. But I was wondering if 2 vectors in R3 also mean linearly independent.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 2 vectors will be dependent if one is a multiple of another. Is this the case in your example ?

Comment: Yeah that was the question I was given. I was just wondering if there was another way in solving it

Comment: Look at whether the vector product is zero or not

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did the vector product and got 13. Does it mean independent? Is this way true for all questions?

Comment: The vector product (not the dot product you used to get $13$) method works for two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ but does not generalise simply to higher dimensions.  It produces a vector output not a scalar value

Comment: @LonzoIngram Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

No, for example $(1,0,0)$ and $(2,0,0)$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Is there another way to find if it's linearly independent?

Comment: The simplest test is to see if they are multiple of each other for this case. you can also put them as rows of matrix and easily see that they have two pivot columns.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for

- $v_1=(1,2,3)$
- $v_2=(0,2,3)$

we have that

- $v_3=v_1-v_2=(1,0,0)=e_1$
- $v_2=(0,2,3)=2e_2+3e_3$

thus $v_3$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent and thus also $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent.

The standard method to check in general linear independence is to arrange vectors in  a matrix and determine the rank by RREF or determinants.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I just want to see if I am correct. If you put it into a matrix and find a zero row(infinitely many solutions) it means linear DEPENDENT. For determinant, if it does NOT equal 0 it is independent. I'm not sure how to find it using rank. Can you please explain that to me. Thanks I appreciate it

Comment: @LonzoIngram Yes arranging vectors by rows by RREF if we find a zero row we can conlude for the linear dependence.